# How do I set up the User ID in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Following the documentation [Set up the User ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666) it states:

> The User ID is set at the property level. To find a property, click Admin, then select an account and a property. From the Property column, click **Tracking Info** then **User ID**.

I've looked at this and the screenshot below shows that for my profile (using Universal Analytics), there is no **User ID** option below **Tracking Info**.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there any better documentation for setting up User ID? A video even?

[image: Google Analytics Property Settings]

**FWIW:** My site is definitely sending the user id to Google Analytics -- the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) Chrome extension gives the following output:

```
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j18d&a=434892113&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fread-able.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=The%20Readability%20Test%20Tool&sd=24-bit&sr=1440x900&vp=1126x688&je=1&fl=12.0%20r0&_utma=147368500.818946455.1393192543.1396643738.1396900196.7&_utmz=147368500.1393192543.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)&_utmht=1396915192983&_u=MCCCg~&jid=600367557&cid=818946455.1393192543&uid=ghi-456-rst&tid=UA-920590-2&z=833810348


adSenseId        (&a)   434892113 
apiVersion       (&v)   1 
clientId         (&cid) 818946455.1393192543 
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 
flashVersion     (&fl)  12.0 r0 
hitType          (&t)   pageview 
javaEnabled      (&je)  1 
joinId           (&jid) 600367557 
language         (&ul)  en-us 
location         (&dl)  http://read-able.com/ 
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit 
screenResolution (&sr)  1440x900 
title            (&dt)  The Readability Test Tool 
trackingId       (&tid) UA-920590-2 
userId           (&uid) ghi-456-rst 
viewportSize     (&vp)  1126x688 
Sent Display Join Beacon: (jid="600367557") 
http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/collect?t=dc&aip=1&v=1&_v=j18d&tid=UA-920590-2&cid=818946455.1393192543&jid=600367557&z=1612498098

apiVersion (&v)   1 
trackingId (&tid) UA-920590-2 
clientId   (&cid) 818946455.1393192543 
joinId     (&jid) 600367557
```

Comment: If you have enabled it and add the JS code to add it, then you have set it up.  I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I run into the same issue. Nowhere I see the option to enable User ID

Comment: Thanks Ivo. That's a big help. I can simply forget about it for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this same question here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/COvwmhZhE8c

And apparantly the functionality is not completely rolled out to all accounts yet.

---

**Edit:**
The April 2 post "[Universal Analytics: Out of beta, into primetime](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/universal-analytics-out-of-beta-into.html)" on the Google Analytics blog says:

> We’re also gradually rolling out the User ID feature to help you better understand your customers’ full journey.

Comment: Oh boy. Still, at least that's an answer. The documentation could handle a little polish then ;)

Comment: [This post](http://www.metricmogul.co.uk/introduction-user-id-override-universal-analytics/) suggests "us Brits won’t be seeing it anytime soon (legal reasons)." -- I hope this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue as well. If you are starting from scratch you can kill the profile that doesn't show "User-ID" in the tracking.js section within admin and try to create a new one until you get the user-id settings page. I would recommend this because there is some bugginess in the reporting when trying to fire multiple trackers from an account which has this functionality vs. ones that dont. Ironically the tracker without this functionality will log correctly where-as the "updated" tracker doesn't track anything. bizarre...